# Oracle external table with dba's directory

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, external-tables

I wanted to create an external table, but did not have the `CREATE ANY DIRECTORY` permission (and could not have it granted). Fair enough, I asked the DBAs to run the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY ext_data_files AS '/data/ext_data_files';
GRANT ALL ON DIRECTORY ext_data_files TO MYAPPUSER;
```

They did, and the final object has the following script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY 
EXT_DATA_FILES AS 
'/data/ext_data_files';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SYS.EXT_DATA_FILES TO MYAPPUSER;
```

(I got that from asking a `desc` with Toad)

I was then hoping to use this directory to create my external table with the script as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MYAPPUSER.MY_EXT_TABLE
(
  ID                VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  LOGIN             VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  CODE              VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  CREATED_AT        VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY SYS.EXT_DATA_FILES
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    NOBADFILE
    NOLOGFILE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    ( ID, LOGIN, CODE, CREATED_AT) )
     LOCATION (SYS.EXT_DATA_FILES:'the_external_file.txt')
  )
REJECT LIMIT 0
PARALLEL ( DEGREE DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT )
NOMONITORING;
```

but then when I `SELECT * FROM MY_EXT_TABLE`, the result is the infamous

> ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
>       ORA-29400: data cartridge error
>       KUP-04040: file the_external_file.txt in EXT_DATA_FILES not found
>       ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 19

(which has quite a few hits on google, but none seem related)

I'm confident of the syntax since this is the exact same script used in our DEV environment. Also, the permissions of all files and directories involved were checked and there is nothing lower than `775`.

The only difference I have here from DEV (where it works) is that the directory `EXT_DATA_FILES` was not created by MYAPPUSER. I tried to create a synonym for it.. but had no effect.

Maybe worth mentioning, it is Oracle 10g we are talking about.

Am I missing something obvious? Is this allowed?

Comment: 1. Why in sys? Couldn't the DBA's have created it in the correct schema? 2. Does you file actually exist in the directory?

Comment: does the txt file actually exist?

Comment: Well, this directory should be used by more than one schema.. I thought it kind of made sense to be in SYS or somewhere common to all users. As for the files, yes it exists and as I mention "the permissions of all files and directories involved were checked". :/

Comment: @Ben: Directories don't have schemas, they all belong to SYS (as of 11gR2)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat, You learn something new every day! Never had to create one in 11gR2 as yet...

Comment: Bahh. Shame on me. Found it. All files and permissions were there alright, one small issue thought. They moved the whole friggn' DB and didn't mount back some of less used FSs back after the migration (and as Murphy predicted, I picked one of these for my external table). From my app POV was all fine, but Oracle didn't have the FS to query. Sorry to bother you guys with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All directories are in fact owned by SYS.  That's why there is no CREATE DIRECTORY privilege, only CREATE ANY DIRECTORY.

So try the command without prefixing the directory name with the SYS schema and see what happens.

Comment: Same result without the SYS.. It actually was the original script. I added the SYS to make it explicit in the question. Good to know that anyway. The error should be elsewhere.

Comment: Just found something interesting: In my dev env. if I do `desc EXT_DATA_FILES` it shows the description of the object. Now, in the prod env. if I do the same `desc EXT_DATA_FILES` it wont work, it will however show the description if I add the SYS. to it, e.g. `desc SYS.EXT_DATA_FILES`. Would this be a clue somehow? @VincentMalgrat this would also make sense to you? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads:
"file the_external_file.txt in EXT_DATA_FILES not found"

Are you sure it's there?